# Are symbolic programming and metaprogramming the same thing?

Tags: meta-programming

Are [symbolic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_programming) and [metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) the same thing?

I've always read about symbolic programming while using Mathematica, but I've never searched about it's meaning, I've searched about it today and I found that both concepts are similar, are there any differences?

Answer (score 4):

Symbolic programming is about manipulating symbolic structures, usually representing formulas, and computing consequences.  Mathematica manipulates math formulas by using rewriting techniques to help people gain insight into their meaning.  Prolog uses backward chaining to find consequences.   Constraint systems solves sets of constraints for answers. 
These systems tend to mix rewriting, theorem proving, constraint propagation, pattern matching and forward/backward inference to achieve the desired effect.

I think of metaprogramming as a special kind of symbolic programming, in which the symbolic structures represents facts about or pieces of (including entire) programs.   One of most general metaprogramming techniques is [program transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation), providing the ability to manipulate program source in roughly the same way as mathematics enables one to manipulate math formulas.

As a practical matter, metaprogramming can use all the techniques of symbolic programming.  It also uses lots of specific algorithms which most people consider to be compiling (e.g., data flow analysis) but is really computing with facts encoded efficiently, so for me most compiling is symbolic computing.

Comment: (I'm not 100% convinced Mathematica uses the term in the same way other people do, though.)

Comment: @Dave: which term (metaprogramming, symbolic computation) is "Mathematica" (company? article? tool? docs? random blogger?) is not using  "in the same way"?

Comment: "Symbolic programming." The company.

Comment: I think of what MMa does as a great example of symbolic programming.  How are they using it wrong?

Comment: (1) I didn't say they were: I said that I'm not convinced they mean the same thing as other people may. (2) I didn't say Mathematica *isn't* an example of a symbolic programming environment, I said I'm not sure they mean the same thing as other people. IMO they're referring to it in the mathematic sense, or something. Making a claim in (2000ish?) that they created a "dramatic change" by introducing symbolic programming to me pretty much implies they're talking about something different, because that's what Lisp was already.

Comment: I think you're just seeing marketing hype; MMa is hardly the first symbolic manipulation system.  Mathematics manipulation systems have been around since the 1960s (MacSyma originally based on Lisp? is one of them I think), and LISP pretty much predates that as one of the earliest symbolic programming systems. (I think there were other early ones, like Tonge's IPL IV).  But I wouldn't worry about whether marketing hype was accurate or not.

Comment: Hence me not believing they're using it in the same way as the world writ large, because even for marketing hype, it's a bit beyond the pale. Just my opinion.

Comment: Interesting! so the concept of *applicative programming* (for example, Lisp's *apply*, *map*, *reduce*...) is to be understood as a subset of both symbolic and metaprogramming? And could this be extended to any other *higher-order function*?

Comment: Lisp's concepts of "applicative programming" are just those of mathematics.  They came about because Lisp's data structures  ("list") are used to model sets of values and operations on sets are convenient whether you are operating on sets of numbers or sets of equations. I think these are orthogonal to the idea of "symbolic computing"; the latter is any computation that is done on "symbols" rather than numbers.  You can do symbolic computation in Fortran by simply interpreting numeric values as corresponding to symbols, and that's how Wolfram built the first version of what became Mathematica.